# how to resize and position textview and label automatically in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, textview, label, autoresize

I am trying to place a text view which will have several lines of varying text and a corresponding label below it. The text view should autoresize according to its contents and the label should appear in the next line of the last line of the text view.
I have been trying to do this for the past few days and wasted a lot of time. If anyone could guide me in the right direction with links or code snippets, it will very helpful

Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

This is not fare.But as far as my knowledge you can do like this.i.e take the length of one line of the textview.And take your string length also.Divide these two.then you will be getting the no of lines.Based on that you  have to adjust the size of textview.